# changing title of UIButton not working

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have added a button in tableview cell. My problem is this when I change its title on calling method `pressHonkBtn:(id)sender` it's not changing its title.

How to solve this.

Comment: thnx to all, my problem solved

Comment: Your Welcome mu dear...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use your code as this :

**Objective-C:**

```
-(IBAction)pressHonkBtn:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *tempBtn = (UIButton *)sender;
    [tempBtn setTitle:@"YOUR_TITLE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];// YOUR_TITLE is your button title
    [tempBtn setTitle:@"YOUR_TITLE" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

**Swift:**

```
someUIButton.setTitle("String To Set", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: there is no need to set the title for state highlighted.

Comment: @Divz I think you are not aware of this. We need to set title for highlighted state too.

Comment: i think you should do it by your self i am confident about it.

Comment: Do it one more time without setting the state highlighted.

Comment: -1 , Until-unless there is no need to have different title for highlighted state , you are not required to set the title for highlighted state simultaneously

Comment: @Gaurav I used this line because if user need to set title for highlighted state then he can set it . So this can not be the reason for downvote.

Comment: @NishantTyagi the reason you are giving doesn't justifies the answer you provided as you are passing the same Title for both states .

Comment: @Gaurav I think you  must have such sense if I have set YOUR_TITLE then it specifies you can set your custom title as per your requirement.

Comment: For some reason, it works for me... Had to se the highlighted state too.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use this one.....It will work fine.

```
-(IBAction)pressHonkBtn:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    [btn setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(IBAction)pressHonkBtn:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [btn setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Since your are recieving the id as argument you need to type cast it to UIButton .

```
-(IBAction)pressHonkBtn:(id)sender
 {
    UIButton *senderBtn = (UIButton *)sender;

    [senderBtn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable critics , can I know the reason for down vote